PHP Desktop with mysql
I downloaded php desktop from the following github repository: https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop.
However, from what I checked, it doesn't even come with the pdo_mysql extension in PHP Version 7.2.12.
In the folder I downloaded there is a php.ini file and it already includes the extension=pdo_mysql but it doesn't and it generates this error for me:

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: /home/cz/github/phpdesktop-linux70/build/php-7.2.12/dist-install-exec-prefix/lib/php/extensions/no -debug-non-zts-20170718/pdo_mysql (/home/cz/github/phpdesktop-linux70/build/php-7.2.12/dist-install-exec-prefix/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non- zts-20170718/pdo_mysql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory),

I hope to connect my php desktop with mysql

like the  repository readme it is to be used as portable implementation and prefer sqlite as db. how will you use this with mysql unless its not installed .

That project has seen it's last release five years ago. Are you sure you want to build a project based on that? Also, if you need support for that software itself, please use their issue tracker
